# Table doesn't exist after CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, symfony, xampp, mysql-error-1146

I'm trying to import this sql in my database name symfony

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ingredient (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and i get

```
#1146 - Table 'symfony.ingredient' doesn't exist
```

This seems rather odd since i'm trying here to CREATE this table, so... why is it not working ?
I've got the same problem if i try

```
CREATE TABLE symfony.ingredient
```

Or the feature in symfony 2

```
c:\Dev\Symfony>php app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

PS: I have this problem only with the new version of xampp.

**EDIT**

Well, i somehow managed to solve my problem.
I dropped my database, then created one (not with the interface) and finally i restarded mysql service.
I don't know why and how it unstuck me, but i hope this will help someone.

Comment: Agreed. I had to drop the database, restart to mysql server, and then recreate everything and it worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks guys, the "table does not exist AFTER a create table" was driving me CrAzY!

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem.
My solution:
Change table name in the create table query, exequte it and then rename the table.

Then, you can also drop this table and after it create it without getting error.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I got a table already existing error when trying to rename another table to the name I wanted.

Comment: Strange, but this works, change name in the create statement and then rename it back to what the original name was needed to be, after the table is created successfully. Can someone throw some light what is happening here?

Answer (score 11):

What worked for me was:

- Going to the folder xampp/mysql/data/database-name/
- You'll see only the `.frm` file. The files `.MYD` and `.MYI` are missing for empty tables.
- Delete the `.frm` file.
- Stop MySQL process and restart it.
- After that I was able to create the table.

The old version of xampp created tables in MyISAM format the new version as InnoDB!

Comment: on Ubuntu files are in /var/lib/mysql/[database-name]

Comment: Yes! This worked for me too.

Just remember that its usually <XAMPP root folder>/xamppfiles/var/mysql/<database_name>/<table_name>.* files that are to be deleted

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem. I got a "server went away" message when creating the table and after that I was getting table doesn't exist messages, but I couldn't try to re-create the table because then I got a message saying that it *did* exist. I solved it by executing this at the command line:

```
mysqlcheck --repair --all-databases -u root -p
```

It also wouldn't hurt to restart the mysql server after this as well just in case.

Comment: @aowie1 Actually, it *does* work with InnoDB, however whatever was happening on my server may be different than what is happening with yours. Even the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlcheck.html) talks about InnoDB tables.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, are you sure you have a database and are priviledged to do CREATE statements.

If you have phpmyadmin:

To test the first possibiblity, create a new (empty) test database, click it in the menu and 
then press the SQL button in the top navigation and copy paste your statement again. If this doesn't work try the second.

For the second you can click on the 'home' button and then go to 'Privileges'. If there are only two or three accounts, but all with root privileges, you have the privileges to do a CREATE. Otherwise you can check your account and give yourself the privileges.

If both possibilities didn't work-out I don't know either. It worked fine for me :(

Comment: Sadly, i'm logged as root, and I test my queries with Phpmyadmin.
What's really odd is CREATE TABLE symfony_ingredient is actually working but that's not what i want. I think something's messed up with the prefix.

Comment: Ah yes, then I am affraid I cannot help you, since I can't reproduce the error, nor see anything that can cause it. Good luck though :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: #1146 - Table 'tutsplus_ci.posts' doesn't exist. I solved this issue following these steps:

I made an export of the incriminated table in a sql file. I noticed that the table name in the .sql file   has a suplemental trailing space. 
I switch back to phpmyadmin in Operations section of my table and I rename the table from ' posts' to 'posts'. After taken all these actions the error didn't show up.

To conclude, indeed the table 'posts' didn't exist as error message said. Because the the actual name of the table was ' posts' not 'posts'. The space before the name is hard to be notice in phpmyadmin. This is the story. Nothing special.
I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the database in phpadmin and in sql drop the table .Then create the table.

Answer (score 0):

may case in win & mac with case-insensitive fs

```
lower_case_table_names=1
```

reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names