# Create table if not exists return "the table doesn´t exist"

Tags: mysql, import

I have a problem in mysql, i try to run this sentence

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comunidad_estado (
  id_comunidad_estado int(11) NOT NULL,
  nombre varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  id_pais int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=56 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and the return is this:

[image: https://imageshack.com/i/pdR670xhp]

I know my db is empty but i can´t understand why does not it create the table

[image: https://imageshack.com/i/idnYVanJp]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried this statement on mysql 5.6 and it worked, further you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142002/table-doesnt-exist-after-create-table

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't run because it works fine on my side.

Comment: @AnilKumar wow, I searched just before and I didn´t found nothing, but by the way it was the solution, I have just created the table with other name, and then renamed it, it´s working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has the same mistake I solved it by changed the name of the query and then rename de db, a really weird work but It´s working. 
Thanks to Anil for the reference: 
[Table doesn't exist after CREATE TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142002/table-doesnt-exist-after-create-table)

Answer (score 0):

It seems, schema / database is corrupted / locked.

Possible solutions:

- Restart mysql service and try again (Sometime lock applies to schema, and somehow doesn't unlock)
- Drop this schema, create new schema and try again (Sometime, on creation of schema - it get corrupted)
- Repair mysql (`mysqlcheck --repair`) - to fix corrupted schemas.
- Last, check permission.

To confirm your script, try @ http://sqlfiddle.com/ . If it works, then above possible reasons with your schema / database.